# netty SimpleChannelInboundHandler message receive only upto 16384

Tags: netty

I have written a netty server using http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html link. But I am getting data only upto 16384 bytes.

```
public class DiscardServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter 
{   
    byte bNullArray[] = "".getBytes();
    String strFullData= new String(bNullArray,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);        
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception  
    { 
        try 
        {
           String MsgRead;
           ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
           MsgRead=in.toString(io.netty.util.CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
           // here I get data only upto 1024 and this method get called 16 times.
           // So total data received is == 1024*16 = 16384        
           strFullData = strFullData + MsgRead;    
        } 
        finally 
        {
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
        }
    }    
    @Override 
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception 
    { 
        //WriteMyLog(strFullData);      
        //Here size of strFullData is 16384        
        strFullData = ProcessMyData(strFullData);       
        byte[] respByteBuf = strFullData.getBytes();                   
        ByteBuf Resp1 = ctx.alloc().buffer(respByteBuf.length);    
        Resp1.writeBytes(respByteBuf);                
        ctx.write(Resp1);            
        ctx.flush(); 
        ctx.close(); 
    }
}
```

How can I get more data?

Answer (score 1):

When your OS reads some data from socket it than passes it to user space (Java with netty in your case). 16 * 1024 is size of buffer that your OS reads from socket and than passes to you. This means `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` handler is not suitable for your case if your messages exceed this size. You need to use `ByteToMessageDecoder`. Something like :

```
public class MyBigMessageDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) { 
        if (in.readableBytes() < MY_BIG_MESSAGE_SIZE) {
            return; 
        }

        out.add(in.readBytes(MY_BIG_MESSAGE_SIZE));
    }
}
```

Netty also has a bunch of ready handlers for different scenarios, like `LineBasedFrameDecoder`, `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder`, `FixedLengthFrameDecoder`, etc. I believe you can use some of them.

In general they all do the same - continue reading of income bytes until some condition met. And when ready - they pass read bytes further.